# Add node to top

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

Whenever I add a new item (*root* or *child*) to a `treeview`, this is *appended* to the list (to the bottom of the whole tree).

Is there a way so I can always insert the new items, even for a child node, to the very top of the list or maybe set the order for the inserted items?

**P.S.** I know how to find the top root, but then I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Add, try using Insert:

```
If TreeView1.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
  TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes.Insert(0, "First Child Node")
End If
```

or for the root node:

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Insert(0, "First Root Node")
```